# difference between property and method of an instance

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

Im reading the tutorials here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/objects-and-classes.html and an on the second paragraph of the Dot Notation section. It uses the 'Sprite' class in ActionScript 3. The tutorial created an instance of the Sprite class and called it myFirstObject. It says..

"Then, using that reference variable and dot notation, values are assigned to the x and visible properties of the instance, and the methods startDrag and stopDrag are called."

I noticed that there are no () after a property. For example:
myFirstObject.x = 300;

compared to a method

myFirstObject.startDrag();

So, what's the difference between a property and method of an instance? I think it would help if I can see the Sprite class but I wasn't able to find it when I tried google'ing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A property has a Get() and Set() method that allow you to use the same call to get or assign a value. When you assign the property a value, you are calling the Set method. When you retrieve a value, you are using the Get method. Properties automatically call the appropriate Get or Set method based on the operation.

To help you visualize the setup, here is a sample property (VB.Net):

```
Private _name As String

Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return _name
    End Get
    Private Set(ByVal value As String)
        _name = value
    End Set
End Property
```

To call it, you would use:

```
MyObject.Name = "Test" <- Sets the name to test
MsgBox("The name is: " & MyObject.Name) <- Gets the value of name
```

Although the example is in VB.Net, the theory is still the same.

A method, on the other hand, would be the equivalent of either the Get or Set routines. As a method, you have to call it and supply the parameters inside of the parenthesis. Even if it has none, you still need the (). When you want to update a variable, you have to pass values to the method instead of setting it equal to the value.

Here is a similar example:

```
Private _name As String

Public Function Name(Optional ByVal strName as String = "") as String
    If strName <> "" then
        _name = strName
    End If
    Return _name 
End Function
```

Here is a similar example of how to use it:

```
MyObject.Name("Test") <- Sets the name to test
MsgBox("The name is: " & MyObject.Name()) <- Gets the value of name
```

Comment: This question was tagged with ActionScript 3 why would you post an answer in vb.net of all things. A property in AS3 does not need a getter and setter defined to "access" or "assign" to a class property.

Answer (score 0):

Properties and methods are similar in that both are implemented as procedures that accept arguments. In general, properties store data for an object, and methods are actions an object can be asked to perform.